# Sharepoint Online Outlook 2016 Task Sync

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I would like to sync a SharePoint Online Task list with Outlook 2013/2016 and then filter the tasks to only

```
Display items assigned to the current user and the status of the task to not equal completed.
```

Is this possible? Can someone direct me in the right direction?

I can sync the list but the filters in Outlook aren't working

I have tried this now with multiple users all with the same results. I can sync entire Task List Items but I can't filter out non-complete tasks and display only the logged in user.

Comment: are you edit the view to filter with also status ?

Comment: Yes I have tried this too, and Outlook still pulls all tasks in the list and no filters

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately,I found out that Outlook doesn't understand the SharePoint views or custom fields.

To filter it down you would need to set a filter in each user's Outlook. as mentioned at this [article](http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-tasks-lists-microsoft-outlook/#.V5bSDfkrLcc)